# C++ proper way for solve this inheritence include issue "already has a body"?

Tags: c++, inheritance, include, dependencies, header-files

Heyo, I have a question about this issue I am having in C++. I am new to C++ and learning. I have experience in object oriented programming so I am looking for the correct way and solve this issue and why it should be done that way.

### Classes

I have separated each class into an interface header file and implementation cpp file.

The first class "Alpha" is my base class:

```
// a.h
#pragma once

class Alpha
{
public:
    virtual void myFunction();
};
```

Alpha Implementation:

```
// a.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "a.h"

void Alpha::myFunction()
{
    std::cout << "Class Alpha myFunction" << std::endl;
}
```

I then have a sub class "Beta":

```
// b.h
#pragma once
#include "a.h"
#include "a.cpp"

class Beta : public Alpha
{
public:
    virtual void myFunction();
};
```

Beta Implementation:

```
// b.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "b.h"

void Beta::myFunction()
{
    std::cout << "Class Beta myFunction" << std::endl;
}
```

I then have what will be like a manager class called "Gamma".

```
// g.h
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include "a.h"
#include "a.cpp"

class Gamma
{
public:
    void run();
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Alpha>> alphaCollection;
};
```

Gamma implementation:

```
// g.cpp
#include "g.h"
#include "b.h"
#include "b.cpp"

void Gamma::run()
{
    Beta localBeta;

    alphaCollection.push_back(std::make_shared<Beta>(localBeta));

    // example usage
    alphaCollection.at(0)->myFunction();
}
```

Then finally my main:

```
#include "g.h";
#include "g.cpp";

int main()
{
    Gamma objectG;
    objectG.run();
}
```

### Why I am doing this

The purpose for all of this being that I want a vector of the base class Alpha in my manager where I can then insert elements of a varying number of base class objects.

I used Beta as an example of a derived class but in the real implementation would have more derived classes such as Charlie, Delta etc.

The goal being that my Manager class Gamma will be able to operate on the vector elements as Alpha objects and each of the sub classes perform their own behavior.

### The Problem

I cannot compile the above example because of how Gamma's implementation file includes "g.h" and "b.h" each of which include "a.h" and "a.cpp" thus double including "a.cpp" since it has no header guard.

- *error C2084: function 'void Alpha::myFunction(void)' already has a body a.cpp*
- *error C2264: 'Alpha::myFunction' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called g.cpp*

I have read varying opinions on how to use includes and overall I just feel like a noob in understanding the proper way to organize code to prevent his.

1. Am I very disorganized?
2. Should implementation files use header guards too?
3. Should I be using forward declarations? If so how?
4. Am I crazy to want the implementation to include the sub class includes while the header includes the base class include only?

**Seriously any guidance is appreciated!**

Comment: You only need to include header file, not .cpp files. And yes, its a good idea to use header guards (in the header files, not the .cpp files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not `#include` the cpp files. It's not required and that's what is causing the issue.

`#pragma once` is the same as an include guard - but remember it's not portable - it's specific to your current compiler.

You should not have include guards in your cpp files because you shouldn't `#include` them.

Comment: Thanks I will swap out the header guards and stop the noobish cpp includes. Hooray

Answer (score 0):

Stop #including .cpp files.  The .h is the most you'll ever need, and sometimes just a forward declaration is enough.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893421/c-header-and-cpp-includes), [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35375/what-to-do-if-i-hate-c-header-files), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904530/understanding-header-and-source-files-in-c) are decent descriptions of what purposes they serve.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to include header files, not .cpp files.

You do not want to use header guards in .cpp files.

You don't need forward declaration here (although you could use it instead)

Your implementations are not including "sub class includes", they are including the header files that define their interface. Your include of a.h is correct in g.h.